# Get method Caller (Controller Name and Action Name ) in castle windsor interceptor method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, system.reflection

I want to find Controller and Action name in dynamic proxy interceptor method 
i check stack trace approch not good way beacase it not last in stack 
this my code

**global asax castle config**

```
IWindsorContainer ioc = new WindsorContainer();
ioc.Register(
Component.For<IMyService>().DependsOn()
.ImplementedBy<MyService>()
.Interceptors<MyInterceptor>()
.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(ioc));
ioc.Register(
Component.For<IInterceptor>()
.ImplementedBy<MyInterceptor>());
```

**controller class**

```
private IMyService _service;
public HomeController(IMyService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    _service.HelloWorld();

    return View();
}
```

**service class**

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
        throw new Exception("error");
    }
}
public interface IMyService
{
    void HelloWorld();
}
```

**interceptor class**

```
//i want to find Controller name  

public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        //?? controller name ?? method Name  
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamicProxy does not expose caller information.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to get the class name and method name in my loggingInterceptor

using *invocation.TargetType.Name*

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{ 
    ...

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Logger.InfoFormat(
                "{0} | Entering method [{1}] with paramters: {2}",
                invocation.TargetType.Name,
                invocation.Method.Name,
                this.GetInvocationDetails(invocation));

            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Logger.ErrorFormat(
                "{0} | ...Logging an exception has occurred: {1}", invocation.TargetType.Name, e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Logger.InfoFormat(
                "{0} | Leaving method [{1}] with return value {2}",
                invocation.TargetType.Name,
                invocation.Method.Name,
                invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: thank you but i want Caller class Name and method not Called Class and method ! i use Enterprise Library Instance of castle and work correctly